# Best, easiest way to do smooth collision?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, collision

So now I am trying to make my game have somewhat smooth, and easy to make, collision. What I am trying to do is make the game add each dimension of the vector one at a time so if only the X value can change, then it will only change on the X value. The example code is below.

Code notes:

- Uses C# with added XNA libraries.
- The IsCollision method sees if the two models inputed are inside of each other.
- The player model is just a box and the floor is just a floor.
- The X, Y, and Z are the cameras location and the lookAt Vector is where the camera is looking.
- The norm Vector is added on to the X, Y, Z, and lookAt in order to create movement.
- the game is in 3D.

Code:

```
//Forward movement
if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) || pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.Y >= 0.2)
        {
            //Check X axis
            playerCollisionMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(X - 10, Y - 10, Z - 10) + (norm + new Vector3(Vector3.Normalize(lookAt).X, 0, 0) / 10));
            if (!IsCollision(playerModel, playerCollisionMatrix, floor, floorMatrix)) norm += new Vector3(Vector3.Normalize(lookAt).X, 0, 0) / 10;
            //Check Y axis
            playerCollisionMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(X - 10, Y - 10, Z - 10) + (norm + new Vector3(0, Vector3.Normalize(lookAt).Y, 0) / 10));
            if (!IsCollision(playerModel, playerCollisionMatrix, floor, floorMatrix)) norm += new Vector3(0, Vector3.Normalize(lookAt).Y, 0) / 10;
            //Check Z axis
            playerCollisionMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(X - 10, Y - 10, Z - 10) + (norm + new Vector3(0, 0,Vector3.Normalize(lookAt).Z) / 10));
            if (!IsCollision(playerModel, playerCollisionMatrix, floor, floorMatrix)) norm += new Vector3(0, 0, Vector3.Normalize(lookAt).Z) / 10;
        }
```

There is obviously more than one of these, one for each direction. But what I want to know is if this the best way to do it, or if there another better way?

More code and information is available upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm not sure of any other ways to do this and this works just as needed. The only thing I feel is necessary to add is a way of going up slopes, but besides that this works very well! If anyone comes along with another, better, way of doing it, post and answer! Otherwise, this is the way to do it!